# Formula Logic Woes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to calculate the ROI of the lighting equipment I'm renting, but I can't seem to figure the formula out.

As it stands, a single rental is calculated by:

`=IF(J62>1;((J62-1)*G27)+F27;J62*F27)*I27`

=> `IF(number_of_days>1;((number_of_days-1)*additional_days)+day_rate; number_of_days*day_rate)*quantity`

What I need to do is to be able to calculate the number of the rental instances from the original value.

So lets say

- Client A rented 2x light for 2 days `((140+14)*2)`
- Client B rented 2x light for 3 days `((140+14+14)*2)`
- Client C rented 2x light for 2 days `((140+14)*2)`
  The total should be 952.

Without breaking it down to it's most simplistic form `(140*6)+(14*8)` I cannot seem to get anywhere near the answer I'm after.

I ideally want to have running totals of the number of units rented, the number of days they were rented for, and the number of rental instances.

So

- Client A: Lights (2) + Days (2) ---> Rental Instances (1)
- Client B: Lights (2) + Days (3) ---> Rental Instances (2)
- Client C: Lights (2) + Days (2) ---> Rental Instances (3)
- And when Client D comes along and rents 1 light for 7 days:
  Lights (1) + Days (7) ---> Rental Instances (4)

Totalling **1176** `([A+B+C]952+[D]224)`

How do I make this happen :(

Comment: unfortunately your problem is not really solvable. Just knowing the output (952 in your case), without knowing anything about input, one may think `140*5 + 14*18`, `140*4 + 14*28`...

Comment: What you're asking has nothing to do with ROI, which may confuse people because there is a built-in function to calculate that.  You're describing just some kind of running total of rental charges.  You seem to have a working formula for each one and it looks like you just want to sum the individual amounts, so it isn't clear where you're running into a problem.  Say your client ID and transaction details are in columns A:C and the rental instances are in column D.  =SUM(D:D) would give you a total of whatever is in that column.  Can you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm going to work on a couple of assumptions here.  I will state them and you can modify as needed.

Let's assume Client is column A, # of Lights column B, Days rented is column C and we'll make total charge column D.  You can put Rental Instances in column E (you are giving a formula above but without seeing the spreadsheet I have no idea what each cell is supposed to represent so I'm relettering)

I am assuming you are using a formula that it is $140 to rent one light for one day and $14 for each additional day. We'll leave a row for the headers so in D2:

```
=IF(B2, (140+(C2-1)*14)*B2, " ")
```

In E2 you can simply put 1 and in E3:

```
E2+1
```

Then where ever you'd like your total displayed just put:

```
=SUM(D:D)
```

If I understand correctly, this should take care of what you're trying to do